# How do I expand and simplify two brackets with a minus sign in-between them?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The question is:

$(r^2 + 3t^2 + 9) - (2r^2 + 3t^2 - 4)$

This is the only question of its type and there's no explanation for it.

The other questions don't have a minus sign in-between them.

Thanks.

Comment: Do You know the [distributive property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributive_property)?

Comment: I figured it out! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Peter Melech points out, the solution to this question subtly employs the distributive property. Knowing that
$$
(r^2+3t^2+9)-(2r^2+3t^2-4)=(r^2+3t^2+9)+(-1(2r^2+3t^2-4)) \, \text{,}
$$
we see that the expression equals
$$
(r^2+3t^2+9)+(-2r^2-3t^2+4)=-r^2+13 \text{.}
$$